# Protecting against SQL injection in transaction

Tags: t-sql

How can I protect my program against SQL-injections?

```
USE TSQL2012
GO

DECLARE @query nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @TransactionName varchar(20) = 'Transaction1'; 

BEGIN TRANSACTION @TransactionName

SET @query = 'DELETE * FROM dbo.test'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @TransactionName
```

This code works fine so long as I add ";ROLLBACK" to the beginning of the query.

I have an idea to use a function: replace(query, 'ROLLBACK', '')

Comment: Don't use dynamic SQL and you won't have to worry. There's nothing that *needs* dynamic SQL in what you posted or even a transaction. A simple `DELETE FROM dbo.test` is atomic and safe from SQL injection

Comment: Do you have some *other* code that uses string concatenation to construct queries combined with user input? Post *that* code instead. It's quite possible it can be replaced by a parameterized query, eg `delete from dbo.test where ID=@ID` uses a parameter for the ID value and isn't vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But If I add ";ROLLBACK" to the beginning of the query, my transaction won't make a rollback.

Comment: What does that have to do with SQL injection? As for rolling back, you put `ROLLBACK` after the queries, not before. You call it only if you want to roll back changes. `DELETE FROM Table1` is a query. It doesn't need `sp_executesql` or explicit transactions. `BEGIN TRAN; DELETE FROM TABLE1; ROLLBACK TRAN;` is another query. Again, no need for strings or transactions.

Comment: The code posted in the question mixes up a lot of different things. Named transactions, dynamic queries *and* two rollbacks, one named one not.

Comment: What if the attacker realizes your "defense" and adds a `COMMIT` in his dynamic SQL? Also, attacking with SQL injection is not always about altering data, it's also about reading data that was not supposed to be read (for example, passwords).